Uppercase, lowercase – "in any case"?
Is there a word to say "whether it's uppercase or lowercase"?
When programming, I often face the situation something is working for lowercase only, then I change something so it works for both lowercase and uppercase. How would I express this?
I understand "lowercase" can be written as "lower case" (other question), but can "case" be used alone in that meaning? I am hesitant to write "in any case", because that means something different.
Example:

Feature X now works for uppercase as well.

I rather want to write something like:

Feature X now works for any case.
Feature X now works for both cases.


Case-insensitive is NOT the same as "works with upper or lower case". Consider a function that converts all characters into emojis... something that works with upper and lower case could convert "A" into one emoji and "a" into another, whereas something that was case insensitive would convert both "A" and "a" into the same emoji.

Cambridge Dictionary does include the relevant definition for case:

case [noun]...
[writing]:   [count or noncount] [specialized]
each of the two forms, capital or small, in which a letter of the
alphabet may be written or printed

But the examples it gives only use the compounds upper-case and lower-case.
Here are examples where 'case' is used independently in the required sense:


The values of variables are automatically transformed to lower case. This doesn't make sense in situations where case is important.


[ThoughtSpot Community]


What is interesting is that, while both references say the case is important, neither one says what case should be used.


[Zombo; StackOverflow] [comma moved]


The requirement for lower case is specific to some DNS software. Case is not important in domain names, but some software is poorly
written.


[bkennelly; Diamond Product Expert; Google Support]


Lettercase ...  In scripts with a case distinction, lowercase is generally used for  the majority of text; capitals are used for capitalisation and
emphasis when bold is not available.


[Wikipedia]

To continue on Tinfoil Hats answer, why not simply use:

Feature X is now case insensitive.

Wikipedia

This is the most natural and idiomatic way to write it in documentation.

As your link explains, case sensitivity is about whether uppercase and lowercase are treated as distinct, not whether they're both supported. For example, a case insensitive file system treats foo.txt and FOO.TXT as equivalent file names. The question is looking for a term for supporting both uppercase and lowercase, not a term for treating uppercase and lowercase as equivalent, so "case insensitive" doesn't fit.

Somewhere in between would be "case-preserving", which is how Windows works: it might be named Foo.txt, but it can be referenced as foo.txt, FOO.TXT, foO.tXT, or any other variation, but internally it is saved as Foo.txt. There is not enough information in the OP to determine if this is the case, though, it could really be case-insensitive instead. "Feature X is no longer case-sensitive" covers both situations.

@user2357112 Since we don't know what the feature is, we don't know whether "case-insensitive" would apply or not. If the feature actually is case-insensitive, then describing it as such might be a reasonable way to make the point that multiple cases are supported. (Though I agree with you that "case insensitive" is not the best guess at an answer given the information currently available.)

@user2357112 If the change is that the feature previously only accepted input/arguments in lowercase and now accepts them in any case, but preserves whatever case was given, then ‘case-insensitive’ would of course not work. But then the description given in the question also would not work. Describing that as the feature now “working for uppercase as well” would be misleading and inaccurate – you would then say that Feature X now accepts input/arguments in uppercase as well”.

I would use a hyphen: case-insensitive.

Something that 'works for both lowercase and uppercase' is said to be 'not case-sensitive'.

This – or perhaps more commonly, case-insensitive – is how documentation like the examples given in the question would be written. “Feature X is now case-insensitive”. (Edit: As also given in Snostorp’s answer, which I just saw now.)

This doesn't fit. Something that's not case-sensitive treats lowercase and uppercase inputs as the same as each other. That's very different from saying that something works for both lowercase and uppercase. Linux file name handling works for both lowercase and uppercase, but it'd be highly misleading to describe it as "not case-sensitive".

@user2357112 - OK - I bow to your superior computing knowledge.

Somewhere in between would be "case-preserving", which is how Windows works: it might be named Foo.txt, but it can be referenced as foo.txt, FOO.TXT, foO.tXT, or any other variation, but internally it is saved as Foo.txt. There is not enough information in the OP to determine if this is the case, though, it could really be case-insensitive instead. "Feature X is no longer case-sensitive" covers both situations.

@user2357112 Saying something "works" is far too vague to be able to draw that conclusion.  When something is case-insensitive, it means you can use upper and lower case letters interchangeably with no difference in behavior. Exactly what this means depends on the context. If doing a search, and someone types a word in lower case, do you also want it to match upper case letters? If so, you want it to be case insensitive. If not, you want it to be case sensitive. OP's original description sounds like case-insensitive to me, and without clarification from the poster we're just speculating.

Question: I want to have two files in the same folder, one named REST.txt and the other named rest.txt. Will that work?
Answer: That will NOT work in Windows, but it will work under Linux
Different Question: I want to have one file in a folder that will be overwritten if anyone saves over it, regardless of whether they use upper or lower case letters. Will that work?
Answer: That will work in Windows but will NOT work in Linux.
So saying that something works depends on what the thing is.

(Yes, I'm well aware that the default behavior under windows can be altered to case sensitivity. I'm also aware that Linux file systems can be made insensitive. Doing either of these things is rare and fraught.)

@barbecue: Many many years ago MacOS had a bug where renaming REST.txt to rest.txt didn't work - because both were the same so the change was not recorded. After renaming it was still REST.txt. Renaming REST.txt to REST2.txt and then renaming REST2.txt to rest.txt did work.

Even though "case" alone could work, I think it would be clearer to use "letter cases" instead.
Example:

Feature X now works for both letter cases.

See Wiktionary

letter case (countable and uncountable, plural letter cases)

(typography, uncountable) The distinction between majuscule (uppercase) and minuscule (lowercase) letters.



You could use an adverb and be in pretty good company:

Feature X now works case insensitively.

You could use a noun and be in even better company:

Feature X now works with case insensitivity.

See this Google Ngram for examples (click the bubbles below the graph).

‘With case insensitivity’ seemss awkward, as that's less a feature and more the lack of a feature — ‘with no case sensitivity’ seems better, though I'd recommend the adjectival ‘…is now case-insensitive’ instead.

@gidds — Yes, but as I understood the question, it is not the Feature itself that is case insensitive.
